# timezone and yesterday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a problem with rails timezones.

application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Athens'
```

controller

```
@from = (Time.zone.now-1.day).to_date
@to = (Time.zone.now).to_date
Entry.where(:created_at => @from..@to)
```

This query supposed to list entries which were created yesterday. When i list entries, i see that some entries were created today.

For example:

It is 5:53 am now and i see that the last entry which was created yesterday was created 3 hours ago, it mustn't be smaller than 6 hours. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is probably using UTC timestamps (at least it should be) but `Time.zone.now` is in your local timezone. Then you call `to_date` and lose the timezone information. Try this:

```
@from = (Time.zone.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day.utc
@to   = (Time.zone.now).beginning_of_day.utc
Entry.where(:created_at => @from..@to)
```

So you call [`beginning_of_day`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) to get back to 00:00:00 and then convert to UTC with [`utc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000348) to get your timestamps into UTC to match the database. You want to keep the time-of-day around all through this so that you don't lose track of what's going during the timezone transitions.

Comment: @to should probably be (Time.zone.now).end_of_day.utc

Comment: @DaniG2k I think `beginning_of_day` is right here or at least matches the intent of `(Time.zone.now).to_date` in the question.